# Getting the Item ID based on combination of two columns through Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, id

I have a small requirement where in I would like to get the item id based on combination of 2 columns.

So I have two List which are

- List A
- List B

Now I am getting two columns which are employee name and Project name from  the List A into List B.

What I would like to do is to update the List A with List B details.
For that I should have a unique id of the list item in order to update that list item. but we do not have a particular unique column based on which we can get the list item record so we would like to get the list item id based on combination of Employee name and project name which are in List B.

How can this be done? 
Any help would be appreciated.

we are already getting the employee names and project name based on the selection of employee name in List B from List A.

Comment: Are you using any lookup column from list A to list B?

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap, no i am not i am using a text field. so after the rest api call i am converting the text box to dropdown and appending the values in it.